# Yarn 3 Workspace resolutions

Tags: yarn-workspaces, yarn-v3, chromatic

I'm building a component library in React using Yarn v3 Workspaces to manage my mono-repo. One of the workspaces within the mono-repo is for a Storybook application and I need to pin the version of one of its transitive dependencies due to a bug.

Yarn documentation suggests you can pin a version by defining a `resolutions` section in your `package.json`. I have tried doing this in both the Storybook workspace `package.json` and the mono-repo root-level `package.json` like so:

```js
  // Root-level package.json
  
  "resolutions": {
    "**/enhanced-resolve": "5.10.0"
  }
```

Or

```js
// Storybook workspace level package.json

  "resolutions": {
    "enhanced-resolve": "5.10.0"
  }
```

Neither of the above seem to work. Any ideas?